# i have integrated both google and Facebook in android studio using kotlin profile picture not showing

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-signin, facebook-access-token

*I have integrated Gmail and facebook signin in my app, when I logged in with gmail everything is working fine but with facebook profile picture is not showing*

**this is the code for the signin_activity**

```
class SignInActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignInBinding
    //private lateinit var googleSignInClient : GoogleSignInClient
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in)
        binding = ActivitySignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val currentUser = mAuth.currentUser
        binding.idtv.text = currentUser?.uid
        binding.nametv.text = currentUser?.displayName
        binding.emailtv.text = currentUser?.email
        val imagedp : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.dp)
        Glide.with(this).load(currentUser?.photoUrl).into(imagedp);

        binding.signoutbut.setOnClickListener {
            mAuth.signOut()
            //googleSignInClient.signOut()
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()

            logout()
            val intent = Intent(this,DashboardActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

    }

    private fun logout() {
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        val googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
        googleSignInClient.signOut()
    }
}
```

and I also need the code to clear the cache of Facebook login activity in **kotlin**

please help someone.

Comment: What does `currentUser?.photoUrl` return when you login with Facebook?

Comment: a blank profile picture

Comment: In referring in code. Besides that, are you sure the Facebook account does contain a profit picture?

Comment: yeah i have a profile picture

Comment: while integrating with google photourl(profile pic url) is converted into image using glide

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to get the photo URL this way:

```
val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
auth.currentUser?.apply {
    for (userInfo in providerData) {
        if (userInfo.providerId == "facebook.com") {
            val photoUrl = userInfo.photoUrl
            Log.d("TAG", photoUrl.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will it work if my app is in development in facebook developers?

Comment: It should work in any phase of your project. Have you tried my solution, does it work?

Comment: "It hasn't worked" doesn't provide enough information so I can further help you. What exactly didn't work? Did you get any errors? Please edit your question with what you have tried so far so I can take a look.